# Electron global shortcut to toggle show/hide of menubar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts, electron, menubar

I am trying to add a global shortcut to my Electron app that will toggle showing/hiding it. My app is a menubar app built using [maxogden/menubar](https://github.com/maxogden/menubar) and React.

I have the following code. I've left a couple of bits out just for brevity but this is how I have setup the global shortcuts.

I think it's important to note one of the tips on the `maxogden/menubar` `Readme` too:

> Use mb.on('after-create-window', callback) to run things after your
>   app has loaded

```
const { globalShortcut } = require('electron');
const keyboardShortcuts = {
  open: 'CommandOrControl+Shift+g',
  close: 'CommandOrControl+Shift+g'
}

menu.on('after-create-window', () => {
  globalShortcut.register(keyboardShortcuts.open, () => {
    menu.window.show();
  });
});

menu.on('after-show', () => {
  globalShortcut.unregister(keyboardShortcuts.open);
  globalShortcut.register(keyboardShortcuts.close, () => {
    menu.window.hide();
  });
});

menu.on('focus-lost', () => {
  globalShortcut.unregister(keyboardShortcuts.close);
  globalShortcut.register(keyboardShortcuts.open, () => {
    menu.window.show();
  });
});
```

Once the menubar has first been opened, my shortcut is registered and will work to show the app. However, the code I've implemented to `unregister` the shortcut, and re-register it to hide the app (when showing), doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure if my code to reregister the shortcut is setup within the right event handler i.e `after-show` and `focus-lost`. I have a feeling that these event handlers I'm working within are related directly to my `menu` rather than `menu.window`. This would explain why the reregistration of the shortcut isn't happening, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any idea how I would sensibly set up a global shortcut toggle to open/close my menubar app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the menubar docs (https://github.com/maxogden/menubar) the menubar instance exposes the following methods:

```
{
  app: the electron require('app') instance,
  window: the electron require('browser-window') instance,
  tray: the electron require('tray') instance,
  positioner: the electron-positioner instance,
  setOption(option, value): change an option after menubar is created,
  getOption(option): get an menubar option,
  showWindow(): show the menubar window,
  hideWindow(): hide the menubar window
}
```

Using `menu.showWindow()` & `menu.hideWindow()` instead of `menu.window.show()` & `menu.window.hide()` will work.

I would further suggest that you use the built in events to manage your state, simplifying your code and implementation:

```
const { globalShortcut } = require('electron');

let isShown = false;
menu
  .on('after-show', () => { isShown = true })
  .on('after-hide', () => { isShown = false })
  .on('focus-lost', () => { isShown = false });

globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Shift+g', () => {
  isShown ? menu.hideWindow() : menu.showWindow()
});
```